# constructor with return type, or illegal redefinition of current class-nam

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list

I'm going to create a Linked_List object class, which will be a "template" for creating linked list object. Now,i've written a simple code but have an error that cannot bypass. My code is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class L_List {
    private:
        struct node {
            int data;
            node* next;
        };
        node* top;
    public:
        void L_List():top(NULL) {}
};
int main() {
    L_List list;
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio 2008, i'm getting error on constructor declaration string.
Error is error C2380 - type(s) preceding 'L_List' (constructor with return type, or illegal redefinition of current class-name?). So,what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You should probably spend more time reading and learning a basic C++ language guide.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, constructors must not return anything. The correct definition is `L_List():top(NULL)`.

Comment: void - does that type returns anything?

Comment: @Lacoste No, this is just a syntax constraint. That's how the language is defined.

Comment: Thank for answering my question, but this case i didn't understand. I declared void L_List:top(NULL){} ,it means that i already have a constructor that did not return anything.

Comment: @Lacoste But it's a syntax error. You have to declare constructors without a return type, i. e. as `L_List:top(NULL) {}`, without the `void` keyword.

Comment: ahh,ok now i anderstand

Answer (score 2):

The error

> constructor with return type

says you must remove the return type `void` from your constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class L_List
{
    private:
        struct node
        {
            int data;
            node* next;
        };
        node* top;
    public:
        L_List():top(NULL)
        {

        }
};
int main()
{
    L_List list;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is not a function. It therefore cannot return anything, its purpose is to *construct* the object, i.e setup datafields depending on constructor's parameters.